# Finding the maximal order in a number field

Tags: number-theory

> Finding the maximal order in a number field

Suppose the number field is $K:=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, then $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ is not necessarily the integral closure of $\mathbb Z$ in $K$. I know the maximal order must have the smallest discriminant value among the orders in $K$. Is there a way to determine it ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. One well-known algorithm is the Buchmann-Lenstra algorithm, for which I can't find a copy of the original paper (`J. Buchmann and H.W. Lenstra, Computing maximal orders and factoring over Z_p, preprint`), but which is described in Cohen's *A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory*, section 6.1. I've included the first page below.

On a practical level, you can use PARI (or something that includes PARI, such as Sage) to perform an actual computation. See [this section in the PARI documentation](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html.stable/Functions_related_to_general_number_fields.html#nfbasis).

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

The maximal order is always the ring of integers in the field. You are right, that $\mathbb{Z}(\alpha)$ is not always it, whenever $\alpha^2=2,3 \mod 4$